# TinyMCE inline formats don't work properly

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-4

I'm trying to simply bold, underline etc. text. Any inline format at all.

Whenever I press the button, the format is added to the beginning of the editor - regardless of whether text is highlighted or not.

I want it so that when I highlight text and press "bold", the highlighted text is bold! This default behaviour, so I'm not sure what would be going wrong. The only thing I have changed is removed the H1 format link:

`{title: 'Header 1', format: 'h1'},`

However when I add it back, it doesn't fix the problem.

My init function is:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    element_format: "xhtml",
    theme: "modern",
    plugins : "advlist anchor autoresize charmap code contextmenu emoticons fullscreen insertdatetime layer link lists visualchars textcolor autolink image hr searchreplace table print preview"
});
```

The document is valid xHTML strict.

Thank you

EDIT: The problem seems to be Opera specific. And only affects TinyMCE 4.01